# Are there analytics for YouTube videos by URL source?

Tags: youtube

I want to know how many people played video from any URL.

Are there some ways to get analytics for YouTube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's your video, go to Analytics > View reports > Playback locations > Embedded player on other websites:

[image]

Comment: OK Thank you, that nice. But in specific domain(site), Can i see how much playing from any page?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it wasn't possible when I was using Analytics more often two years ago and before, maybe this feature has been added later on but not to my knowledge. It would be indeed very useful!